# SPLIT_PART with a negative value [Postgres 9.5]

Tags: postgresql, split, postgresql-9.5

I need to use the split_part function on that query:

```
CREATE TABLE client_group_by_group_test AS SELECT *, SPLIT_PART( groupe,
 ',', 1 ) AS group1, SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(groupe,',',2),',',-1) AS 
 group2, SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(groupe,'',3),'',-3) AS group3, 
 SPLIT_PART(groupe,'',-4) AS group4 FROM planification_client
```

but it gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  field position must be greater than zero

So, how can I deal with negative values here?

Can this kind `reverse(split_part(reverse(col_A), '_'::text, 1))` of statement work? I'm referencing to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819485/invalid-length-field-position-must-be-greater-than-zero).

EDIT: I'm completely stuck with this query.

More details: I have one column with "server name" and another with its different groups separated with coma.

```
server name| group                        |
-----------+------------------------------+
XPTERTBIEP9|GRNW_SPO_S_F_H, GRNW_SPO_S_I_J|
```

The output I need to get is if the server has multiple groups, they need to be in the different column like group1, group2...

```
server name| group                        |group1        |group 2
-----------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------
XPTERTBIEP9|GRNW_SPO_S_F_H, GRNW_SPO_S_I_J|GRNW_SPO_S_F_H|GRNW_SPO_S_I_J
```

Comment: Yes, when you want negative offsets than you should go with the `reverse` solution - it works (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46753602)

Comment: Ok, i'm going to test it. Thanks

Comment: What is the negative index supposed to represent? The offset from the end?

Comment: Yes, the negative index is supposed to represents the offset from the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the negative number is supposed to indicated the offset from the end, a two step approach might be better:

```
CREATE TABLE client_group_by_group_test 
AS 
SELECT ..., 
       agroups[1] as group1,
       agroups2[cardinality(agroups2) - 1] as groups2,
       agroups3[cardinality(agroups3) - 3] as groups3,
       agroups[cardinality(agroups) - 4] as group4
from (
   select *,
          string_to_array(groupe, ',') as agroups, 
          (string_to_array(string_to_array(groupe, ','), ',')[2]) as agroups2,
          (string_to_array(string_to_array(groupe, ','), ',')[3]) as agroups3,
   from planification_client
) t
```

Note that you need to list the desired columns in the outer most SELECT to exclude the intermediate "agroups" columns.

Comment: There is an issue with this line  `string_to_array((string_to_array(groupe, ','), ',')[2]) as agroups2,` : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["`
I tried to delete the [] but something went wrong